# getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Hi i am using `getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll()` to save a list of object in my project. but it shows an error :

> The type org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor cannot
>   be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

i am using the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

i couldn't find out the reason of this error. Any body can help me to find the solution?

Comment: Add the class code which showing this exception with imports?

Comment: But when i import that class ,it shows error : The import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor cannot be resolved

Comment: It mean it not download the required jar from repository

Comment: Have you added all dependencies which is required for the application?

Comment: i include the dependencies **<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>                                                                               <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>**

Comment: Is these jar file present in  `.m2` directory and Java class path

Comment: Please add all your dependencies and not as comments but as in improvement to your question. Comments containing large blocks of code/xml are unreadable.